# Helm chart volumes and volumeMounts in deployment file

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm

I can't make my chart use my `volumes`, and `volumeMounts` values. In my values.yaml file I have something like this:

```
volumes:
- name: docker1
  hostPath:
    path: /var/
- name: docker2
  hostPath:
    path: /usr/
- name: docker3
  hostPath:
    path: /opt/
    
volumeMounts:
- name: docker1
  mountPath: /var/
- name: docker2
  mountPath: /usr/
- name: docker3
  mountPath: /opt/
```

In my _deployment.tpl file I have something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  revisionHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.revisionHistory | default 2 }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podAnnotations | nindent 8 }}
      labels:
        {{- include "labels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml .Values.imagePullSecrets | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
              {{- toYaml .Values.image.ports | nindent 10 }}
          env:
              {{- toYaml .Values.env | nindent 10 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{- toYaml .Values.volumeMounts | default "" | nindent 10 }} 
          volumes:
            - name: {{- toYaml .Values.volumes | default "" | nindent 10 }}     
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | nindent 8 }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml .Values.tolerations | nindent 8 }}
{{- end }}
```

I tried to mount volumes and volumeMounts the same way I do with env variables *(they work)* but sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with the indentation of your code.

Volumes should be at the same indentation level as containers.

As follow:

```
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml .Values.imagePullSecrets | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            {{- toYaml .Values.image.ports | nindent 12 }}
          env:
            {{- toYaml .Values.env | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- toYaml .Values.volumeMounts | default "" | nindent 12 }} 
      volumes:
        {{- toYaml .Values.volumes | default "" | nindent 8 }}     
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | nindent 8 }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml .Values.tolerations | nindent 8 }}
```

If you want to debug the template, you can refer to the official helm document operation.

[helm debug](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/)

Comment: It did help a little. I've made a changes regarding `nindend` and removed the ` - name` field in template so it looks like this:
`{{- toYaml volumeMounts... }}`  
After that I got an erorr saying: 
`[ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[1]): unknown field "mountPath" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container, `

Comment: I thought adding a dash before mountPath would change something: 
`volumeMounts:
- name: docker1
- mountPath: /var/`
but it caused another error:
`error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[2]): unknown field "mountPath" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[2]): missing required field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container`

Comment: Yes, `- name` should not be written here, I updated the above response. In addition, if you want to know where the specific template rendering error is, you can use this command: `helm template --debug`. It is definitely wrong to add `-` before both mountPath and name, which is obviously not grammatical

Comment: In addition, the current error is caused by the wrong indentation, you need to adjust your indentation according to the actual situation. In `volumeMounts ` nindent 12.  In `volumes` nindent 8. You can refer to my reply above, I have already updated

Comment: Man, I love you with all my heart